# Swift Protocols and Extension Outside of Module

Tags: ios, swift

I import module X in Y, but when compiling I have an error saying that Type 'ChangePinServiceProvider' does not conform to protocol 'CardPinServiceProvider'. Add protocol stubs: func retrieveCardDetails

I don't intend on using retrieveCardDetails func inside module X because I can't access certain functionality, only the functionality is accessible in Module Y. And I can't change protocol CardPinServiceProvider as it's used by other files. Is there way I can satisfy the conformance Protocol without using retrieveCardDetails inside the file in Module X. Thanks for your help

Module X
**CardPinServiceProviderProtocol.swift** inside Module X

```
public protocol CardPinServiceProvider {
    var accountNo: String { get }
    var cardsManager: CardsManager { get }
    func retrieveCardDetails(forAccountNumber accountNumber: String
}
```

**ChangePinServiceProvider.swift** inside Module X

```
public class ChangePinServiceProvider: CardPinServiceProvider {
    public let accountNo: String
    public let cardsManager: cardsManager
    }

    init(
        accountNo: String,
        cardsManager: cardsManager,
    ) {
        self.accountNo = accountNo
        self.cardsManager = cardsManager
    }
```

Module Y
**CardPinServiceProvider+Extension.swift** inside Module Y

```
import moduleX

extension CardPinServiceProvider {
    public func retrieveCardDetails(forAccountNo accountNo: String) {
       ...code that accesses important functionality inside ModuleY
}
```

Comment: What module is ChangePinServiceProvider in?

Comment: Hi Joakim, module X

Comment: You need to move that extension to module X

Comment: You seem to be using an extension to add a default implementation of `retrieveCardDetails` to the `CardPinServiceProvider`. You have stated that `ChangePinServiceProvider` conforms to `CardPinServiceProvider`, but that class does not implement the function `retrieveCardDetails`, that is required by the protocol, so the error is correct. . Perhaps you should implement a stub of this function in `ChangePinServiceProvider` and then subclass it and provide an override implementation?

Comment: Thanks Paul, appreciate your response. Can the stub of this function be empty, then subclass and provide an override implementation? Unfortantely, I can't do much of this function in ChangePinServiceProvider, it kinda needs to be empty, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there way I can satisfy the conformance Protocol without using retrieveCardDetails inside the file in Module X.

Yes. Don't declare the conformance in module X, declare it in module Y.

**Module X:**

```
public class ChangePinServiceProvider {
    public let accountNo: String
    public let cardsManager: cardsManager
```

**Module Y:**

```
import moduleX

extension CardPinServiceProvider: CardPinServiceProvider {
    public func retrieveCardDetails(forAccountNo accountNo: String) {
       ...code that accesses important functionality inside ModuleY
}
```

In module Y, the requirements for the two properties will be satisfied by the declarations in module X because they are public.